# Very basic questions about linear systems

Tags: linear-systems

*Note: This question may seem extremely elementary, but I am **not** a beginner to signal processing, linear system theory, control theory, etc.*
*I believe my confusion is over a subtle point, so, before responding, please read the entire question so you understand the source of my confusion first.*

---

Consider this simple autonomous system ([autonomous means it has no direct dependence on $t$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)#Definition)):

$$\dot{x}(t) = A x(t)$$

Assume the output is the state ($y(t) = x(t)$) and $A \neq 0$. My questions are:

1. Is this system necessarily linear?
2. Is this system necessarily time-invariant?
3. What is the *zero-input response* of this system?
4. Would the answers above change if we assumed the system was causal?

Easy, right?

1. [Obviously yes, since it is in the form $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)$](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoeldsee263/09-auto-sys.pdf#page=2)
2. [Obviously yes, since $A$ does not depend on $t$](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoeldsee263/09-auto-sys.pdf#page=2)
3. The zero-input response is: $x(t) = x(0)\,e^{At}$
4. No, these are unrelated properties.

**But wait**!

1. Linearity means a linear combination of the inputs must give the same linear combination of the outputs. If I scale the input, $u$, then $x$ is not affected at all. So how can it be linear?!
2. Time-invariance means that if I delay the input, the output is delayed by the same amount of time. But if I delay the input, $u$, then $x$ is not affected at all. So how can it be time-invariant?!
3. If the initial state is an "input": Doesn't linearity imply $x(0) = 0 \implies x(t) = 0$?
   If the initial state isn't  an "input": Isn't the system nonlinear unless $x(0) = 0$? (see #1)
4. Wouldn't *zero-input* give *zero-output* for a causal LTI system (the "ZIZO" property)?

Hopefully it's clear why I'm confused.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You don't have a linear system.  Any otherwise LTI system which exhibits an output component caused by the homogeneous solution (e.g. due to non-zero initial conditions) is no longer linear (or time-invariant).  You've just identified a special case of this fact.

Comment: @PeterK.: I would agree but if you click on my link, Boyd's PDF *does* call $\dot{x} = Ax$ a "continuous-time autonomous linear dynamical system" and also calls it time-invariant, so that is directly at odds with your statement...

Comment: Done!  I hope it's of some help.

Comment: yeah, @PeterK. i remember MattL and i having the same issue.  depends on how one expresses the convolution integral (i like it from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and then identifying $x(0)$ as the result of the integral from $-\infty$ to $0$.  i would say it **is** LTI, but if $x(0) \ne 0$, then you didn't have "ZIZO".  MattL disagrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDSs are systems *of differential equations*. For such things the terms "linear" and "time-invariant" have different definitions when compared with control theory or signal processing. For example [linearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) means `having solutions which can be added together in particular linear combinations to form further solutions`. For example [time-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) means `when the [independent] variable is time, they are also called time-invariant systems.`

Answer (score 2):

The state-space model of a causal continuous-time LTI system is

$$\begin{align}\dot{x}(t)&=Ax(t)+bu(t)\\y(t)&=cx(t)+du(t)\tag{1}\end{align}$$

where $x(t)$ is the state (vector), $u(t)$ is the input, and $y(t)$ is the output.
If the state $x(t)$ is a length $N$ vector, then $A$ is an $N\times N$ matrix, and $c$ is a $1\times N$ matrix (or row-vector, if you like).

In your example, $b=0$, $c=0$, and $d=0$. So there is basically no input and no output. We can only observe the state, i.e., the "internal behavior" of the system. We can only talk about linearity and time-invariance concerning the states. If $A$ is constant, the system is linear and time-invariant in that sense. But since we can't observe a response to an input signal it is impossible to talk about linearity and time-invariance of the system in terms of its input/output behavior. And, consequently, the corresponding tests become pointless.

And concerning point 4. in your question: yes, an LTI system must have zero output for zero input. It is a non-zero initial state that can produce a non-zero output for zero-input, but with a non-zero initial state, a system is not LTI anymore. If it is LTI otherwise (apart from the non-zero initial state), then it can be modeled as LTI by representing the non-zero initial state as an additional input to the LTI system (which must now have a zero initial state, otherwise it couldn't be LTI).

Comment: I'm assuming $y(t) = x(t)$, sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The argument remains the same: if there is no input you can't talk about linearity and time-invariance of the system in the sense of responses to input signals. So those tests (scaling and shifting the input signal) are not relevant and pointless. If you like, it is not a system in the conventional signal processing sense of the word.

Comment: To be clear and explicit, are you saying there are 2 different definitions of linearity and time-invariance, neither of which entirely encompasses the other? Because I fail to see how a single definition can cover both the mathematical sense and the signal-processing sense, yet I have never seen both definitions compared and contrasted side-by-side either, leading me to believe they are not distinct.

Comment: Also, if you truly mean that these are not "systems" in the signal-processing sense, would it be possible for you to provide the formal definition of the word "system" in that sense? (A simple link is fine, but I'm looking for a formal definition, not something hand-wavy.)

Comment: If you talk about the linearity and time-invariance of a system, and both properties are *defined* by the relation between input and output, and now you have a system with no input, there can't be a way to judge those two properties. So I wouldn't say that the definitions are different, but what's happening is that you can't judge input/output linearity (or time-invariance) if either input or output are non-existent. The only thing you can do is test the linearity and time-invariance of the autonomous behavior. Nothing else can be said.

Comment: The trouble I have with your explanation is that you're hand-waving over the problem, whereas I'm looking for a formal explanation that isn't full of loopholes. To give you just one example, if I give you $x_1'(t) = u_1(t), x_2'(t) = x_2(t)$, now my system has an input as well as an output. It might not be controllable, but nowhere have I seen controllability as a criterion for linearity or time-invariance. Have you? How do you rectify this?

Comment: A system (in a signal processing context) is a mapping from an input to an output (signals or sequences). This can be found in almost any book on signals and systems.

Comment: Yes and that is exactly the hand-wavy definition I'm not looking for because it breaks as I explained. The system in my example certainly **is** a mapping from inputs to outputs. It merely happens to multiply the inputs by zero before adding them to the output. That doesn't make it any less of a mapping. How do you rectify this?

Comment: If the output is independent of the input (and if that is really what you mean), then the system (in a SP context) is obviously not LTI. But this is no contradiction with the "system" $x'(t)=Ax(t)$ being a linear dynamcial system, because there we don't consider an input/output relation.

Comment: OK, yes that is really what I mean. If that's the case then could you address [this comment](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29809/very-basic-questions-about-linear-systems/29813?noredirect=1#comment55985_29813)? You are saying there are 2 definitions of linear, one in an SP context and one in a controls context, so I'm just looking for a formal definition of each. (Again, 2 links are fine.)

Comment: The comment-link doesn't work for me. I don't think I said that, but that's what you understood. What it boils down to is this: define exactly what you mean by "system" and people can tell you if it's linear or not. If your system is the LDS you defined in your question, then yes, it's linear (and TI) - as a diff. eq. describing states. If you add an input to it and ask if the system (as a mapping between input and output) is linear, then the answer is no, it's not.

Comment: Er, again, I'm saying it's not as clear-cut as you make it seem. Say my "system" is this: $\begin{bmatrix}x_1'(t) \\ x_2'(t)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1(t) \\ x_2(t)\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}u(t) \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. It is clearly a dynamical system, it is described by an ODE, it does map inputs to outputs, and it does not ignore its inputs. It happens to not be controllable, but that should be irrelevant, right? Now do you really see multiple "systems" here? What are they? Would you call each linear? Time-invariant? Does $x(0)$ matter?

Comment: If this is one system (it could also be two if one wanted to see it that way), then it's a SIMO system, and since one of its outputs is independent of the input, it's not linear neither time-invariant.

Comment: Yes it's *one* system. OK, so if you're saying it's neither linear nor time-invariant, doesn't that completely contradict [line 1 of slide 2 here](http://ee263.stanford.edu/lectures/linsys.pdf), which explicitly calls it a time-invariant linear dynamical system? (Do you see why this is confusing...?)

Comment: I don't think it's a contradiction, because on that slide the system is considered a LDS with NO input, and it's linear in the sense that if $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are solutions, then any linear combination is also a solution. The linearity (and TI) of systems that map inputs to outputs is a slightly different thing, even though the essence of linearity remains the same. The difference lies more in the exact definition of the system (does it have an input or not?)

Comment: What I'm frankly having trouble with is your explanations, not your conclusions. (Your conclusions make sense to me but your explanations don't.) You're saying it depends on the definition of the *system* and whether it has an input or not, but in my last example above and on page 2 of the slides I linked to, both systems explicitly do depend on inputs, yet one of them is called linear and the other one isn't. To me, this makes it painfully obvious that the problem isn't the definition of the "system" or with whether we have inputs, but rather how we define linearity and time-invariance...

Comment: The essence of linearity and time-invariance is always the same. You just need to apply them in a way that makes sense for the given system. If your system has no input, don't try to use the input to define linearity or time-invariance.

Comment: "The essence is always the same" is just intuition though, not something formal. If you can pretend I'm a mathematician and *formalize* this common essence for me to prove that it's identical in both cases, I will be more than happy to believe it. The entire trouble I'm having is that I can "feel" it being the same, but I cannot formalize a definition that is the same across both cases, whereas you're merely declaring that this is possible, which isn't very satisfactory.